# Running Callback Function in Async

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I'm trying to understand how to run callback functions in an async console application.  My base console app code looks as follows:

```
    using Nito.AsyncEx;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        AsyncContext.Run(() => MainAsync());
    }

    static async Task MainAsync()
    {


    }
```

The method that I want to run in Async mode is the following from a websocket api:

```
using ExchangeSharp;

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // create a web socket connection to Binance. Note you can Dispose the socket anytime to shut it down.
    // the web socket will handle disconnects and attempt to re-connect automatically.
    ExchangeBinanceAPI b = new ExchangeBinanceAPI();
    using (var socket = b.GetTickersWebSocket((tickers) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} tickers, first: {1}", tickers.Count, tickers.First());
    }))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to shutdown.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

The above code is meant to lock a console app and subscribe to an event which receives data, and to do something with the received data.

What I want to do is run the above in a separate thread or in async so that I can continue with my code in the MainAsync() function.

My C# experience with this is limited.  Will appreciate any help!

Comment: From what i can gather, if you put more code before `Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to shutdown.");` it will already work asynchronously... its paused on the readline, because the application will exit, this is the normal process of a console app.. Do stuff or wait for input, or terminate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [source code](https://github.com/jjxtra/ExchangeSharp/blob/master/ExchangeSharp/API/WebSocketWrapper.cs) `GetTickersWebSocket` isn't a blocking call.

The only blocking call you've posted is `Console.ReadLine`.
`ExchangeBinanceAPI` has its own callback-based asynchrony, so, just throw away `Console.ReadLine`, or place more code before it:

```
static async Task MainAsync()
{
    ExchangeBinanceAPI b = new ExchangeBinanceAPI();
    using (var socket = b.GetTickersWebSocket((tickers) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} tickers, first: {1}", tickers.Count, tickers.First());
    }))
    {
        // code continues here

        Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to shutdown.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

**As a side note.**

I'm not familiar with this [project](https://github.com/jjxtra/ExchangeSharp), but source code shows poor man's aynchrony inside `WebSocketWrapper`:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(ListenWorkerThread)

// inside ListenWorkerThread
_ws.ConnectAsync(_uri, CancellationToken.None).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
result = _ws.ReceiveAsync(receiveBuffer, _cancellationToken).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
```

and so on.

There are attempts to call asynchronous code in synchronous way.
Instead of this, at least `ListenWorkerThread` must be converted to `async` method, and it definitely must not be called via `Task.Factory.StartNew`.

I'd post a request to rewrite code in true asynchronous manner, if I have to use this project.

Answer (score 1):

Async method would not block the caller thread if you use it directly, you can just call it anywhere before `Consolo.ReadLine()` then use returned `Task` to handle the result if you need.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Would not block the thread.
    Task t = MainAsync();

    // Only if you need. Would not block the thread too.
    t.ContinueWith(()=> { code block that will run after MainAsync() });

    // create a web socket connection to Binance. Note you can Dispose the socket anytime to shut it down.
    // the web socket will handle disconnects and attempt to re-connect automatically.
    ExchangeBinanceAPI b = new ExchangeBinanceAPI();
    using (var socket = b.GetTickersWebSocket((tickers) =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} tickers, first: {1}", tickers.Count, tickers.First());
    }))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to shutdown.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```